# Unable to Open Visual Studio professional 2017 project connected to TFS online

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Unable to sign into TFS online using visual studio professional 2017 v15.2 (26430.14) - Visual Studio locks up few seconds after login dialog appears...

Seems sign-in dlg is displayed as VS attempts to connect to TFS online; but no matter what you do you get locked up 3 secs later.. No matter what... end result is me killing the process and left unable to access any project.

*THE ONLY WAY OUT*  I did figure out that if you cancel(esc key) the dlg closes before it hangs.  you can THEN connect to TFS via team/menus.  life saver.

does anyone know why this happens or how to correct..? seems intermittent but sometimes lasts for days.. meaning, I have to do this on every startup; but then magically the problem goes away.  An associate of mine also sees this problem.

Comment: I had a similar issue with VS 2017. I did a repair install, fixed it for me.

Comment: 1. Clear the cache in C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\[version] 2. Clear credential in credential manager 3. Run devenv /resetuserdata to clear user data. If it still have the issue, try to repair it and check the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this issue is resolved with the latest VS2017 update (15.0.26430.16).

I'm not sure what version you are running, but try updating as it worked for me.

Comment: worked for me as well. see above comments as well as they also yielded some positive results.